# Argument of \verbatim@ has an extra } error while placing a tcolorbox inside a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcblisting

Trying to place a macOS style Terminal inside a node:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,14pt,oneside,]{extbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\definecolor{terminalColor}{RGB}{38,50,56}
\definecolor{Button1}{RGB}{254,94,86}
\definecolor{Button2}{RGB}{254,188,45}
\definecolor{Button3}{RGB}{38,202,59}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}
\begin{document}

\def\bottom#1#2{\hbox{\vbox to #1{\vfill\hbox{#2}}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[color=black,fill=yellow, scale=1.0,transform shape,anchor=north west,
    minimum height=0.5\pageheight,
    minimum width=1.0\pagewidth,] (foo) at (current page.north west) {\bottom{0.45\pageheight}{
       \begin{tcblisting}{width=11cm,listing engine=minted,
        minted style=native, minted language=bash,
        enhanced,colback=white,colframe=gray,
        listing only,title=\tikz{
          \node[circle,fill=Button1,inner sep=3pt] (c) at (0,0){};
          \node[circle,fill=Button2,inner sep=3pt] (c) at (0.5,0){};
          \node[circle,fill=Button3,inner sep=3pt] (c) at (1,0){};
        }
            }
$ ls -lt 
# lists folder contents in date order
       \end{tcblisting}
       }};
% \$ ls -lt 
% \# lists folder contents in chronological order

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

to get the output on the right, gives a
`Argument of \verbatim@ has an extra }` error. If I remove the `tcblisting` block and put simple text inside the node, it compiles fine.

[image]

How to place that `tcblisting` block inside the node correctly?

Note: In order to achieve the same page layout, I've tried putting the `tcblisting` inside a `minipage` but I got the same (or a similar) error.

Comment: So you want a `tcblisting` inside a box, inside a box, inside a box, inside a `tikzpicture`? I'd expect issues.

Comment: @egreg In order to place the tcblisting above the bottom contour of the node, I had to do it like that; agree the code looks convoluted  but as an average TeX user, how else could I achieve that page design :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the defined `bottom` and its offending `}` s and put `text height=0.50\pageheight` inside the options of the (main layout setting) node instead:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,14pt,oneside,]{extbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\definecolor{terminalColor}{RGB}{38,50,56}
\definecolor{Button1}{RGB}{254,94,86}
\definecolor{Button2}{RGB}{254,188,45}
\definecolor{Button3}{RGB}{38,202,59}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[color=black,fill=yellow, scale=1.0,anchor=north west,
    minimum height=0.5\pageheight,
    minimum width=1.0\pagewidth,text height=0.50\pageheight] (foo) at (current page.north west)
         {\begin{tcblisting}{width=11cm,listing engine=minted,minted style=native,minted language=bash,enhanced,colback=white,colframe=gray,listing only,title=\tikz{
                  \draw node[circle,fill=Button1,inner sep=3pt,minimum size=0.2cm] (c) at (0,0) {};
                  \draw node[circle,fill=Button2,inner sep=3pt,minimum size=0.2cm] (c) at (0.5,0){};
                  \draw node[circle,fill=Button3,inner sep=3pt,minimum size=0.2cm] (c) at (1,0){};
               }
             }
$ ls -lt 
# lists folder contents in date order
           \end{tcblisting}
         };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It doesn't work perfectly, i.e. the macOS style Terminal doesn't sit exactly on top of the bottom contour of the node but given the current circumstances, it looks okay

[image]